# Restore/enable wifi when turning off tethering?

Tags: tethering, automation, tasker, wifi-tethering

When I turn on WiFi tethering it disables the WiFi logically. But when I restore it doesn't turn it back on again, so I have to do it manually. Is there any way to do it automatically?

I have a nexus 4 which is rooted and running CarbonROM 1.8.
I tried Tasker, but I found no way to check tethering status.

Comment: Just checked the tasker UserGuide: It in fact doesn't mention anything fitting. What you could try, though, is checking whether the `%WIFII` variable might hold something useful (have it logged or put a notification once with WiFi on, and once with Tether on, and compare – you could do so simply by creating a dummy task and directly execute it manually).

Comment: Tried it, %WIFII doesnt hold any thing related to tethering.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I couldn't tell as I never use Tether, but it was worth a try. Sorry that it didn't work out! If you've bought *Tasker*, you could contact its author. I wouldn't wonder if he'd consider implementing something for that: to me it looks like it should be there but just was missed somehow.

Comment: Newer versions of Tasker now include the %TETHER variable, its now possible to interchange the two (with %WIFI) so you check when either is active or not.